# npm start (localhost:3000) gives me a blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, localhost

Every time I try to use npm start to run localhost:3000 I get a blank page - I had it work briefly yesterday but then today it stopped!

I've even tried using several different pre-made github projects other people have made that use react and I get a blank page with those as well.

Please help!

Comment: In it's current state, it's not possible to answer this question, as you haven't provided any details... Edit your question to include your code, steps to preproduce, expected and actual outcome, and explain what you've tried yourself so far. And for next time, you should read [these guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254573/979052) before posting

Comment: Have you looked in the terminal/console for errors which would be the first stage of debugging code?